# Receive binary 64-bit float from Matlab Simulink on UDP Server in c

Tags: c, matlab, binary, udp

I receive a binary 64bit-float on the udp server in C. I can´t convert the char array buf which receives the binary float to the number. any ideas?

```
rc=recvfrom(s,buf,9,0,(SOCKADDR*)&remoteAddr,&remoteAddrLen);
if(rc==SOCKET_ERROR) {
  printf("Fehler: recvfrom, fehler code: %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
  system("Pause");
  return 1;
} else {
  printf("%d Bytes empfangen!\n", rc);
  buf[rc]='\0';
}
printf("Empfangene Daten: %s\n",buf);
```

Comment: yes I want to convert the buf with binary code to a decimal number.
but i can't use your code.

Comment: [Linker error] undefined reference to `bin2dec'   
[Linker error] undefined reference to `uint64' 
[Linker error] undefined reference to `typecast'
don't know how to fix it.. i am new in C

Comment: My bad. I thought this was Matlab code.

Comment: oh no.. its on the server side.. but thanks

Comment: Show more code, why 9?, use `sizeof(buf)` instead

Comment: `int o;
  for(o=0; o<8; o++)
  buf[o]=0;

          rc=recvfrom(s,buf,sizeof(buf),0,(SOCKADDR*)&remoteAddr,&remoteAddrLen);
          if(rc==SOCKET_ERROR)
          {
           printf("Fehler: recvfrom, fehler code: %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
           system("Pause");
           return 1;
           }
           else
          {
          printf("%d Bytes empfangen!\n", rc);
           //buf[rc]='\0';
         }
          printf("Empfangene Daten: %d\n",buf);
          int u;
          for(u=0; u<8; u++)
          printf("%d\n",buf[u]);`

out:
8Bytes received
DATA: 2686768
0
0
0
0
0
-16
63

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the Solution. I send binary Code... For Exemple the dezimal 322.. If i send it with 32 Bit integer it hat 32 Bits... I Receive it as Char.. One Char is 8 Bit Long... For the decimal 322 i reiceve 0 0 1 66... Its because the binary Code is 00000000 00000000 00000001 01000010 every Char[3] Stands for 0 char[2] for 0 Char[1] is 2 and char[0] is 66... Every Char represents his Own 8 Bit decimal number.. You got it?